# A finite abelian group "take-away" game

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Fix a finite abelian group $G=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{Z}/n_i\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose we play the following game. For any $1 \leq k < |G| $, we choose $k$ elements from the group at random without replacement. If the $k$ elements sum to $0$, we win. Else we lose. Which $k$ should we pick? Of course, $k$ depends on $G$ (which is more or less characterized by the $n_i$'s).

We can ask questions like this for general non-abelian groups, where the order we choose elements matters, and that is precisely the order we perform the group operation. But I suspect it gets hard in this case.

Note I $\textit{expressly exclude}$ the case that $k=|G|$, for the simple fact that it's generally going to be quite likely that the elements sum to $0$ in that case (for instance, if the group has odd order, or has even order and more than one element of order $2$).

Note also that partial answers are acceptable since this seems to be a not-so-easy problem. For instance, if you have an answer for the specific case where $G$ is cyclic, feel free to mention it.

Comment: Sounds like this should be about rings and not groups.

Comment: @Randall Groups. I replaced "multiplication" with "sum" and "$1$" with "$0$", if that resolves the confusion.

Comment: Yep, it does...

Comment: In groups where $k=|G|$ is a solution, there is a symmetry to the problem between $k$ and $|G|-k$.

Comment: I think your trivial case is wrong.  If you have a prime order cyclic group you pick the first $k-1$ elements however and there is one element that will make the sum $0$.  You have $\frac 1p$ chance that that element is available and you pick it, so any $k$ other than $0$ or $|G|$ has equal probability.  As an example, take $p=5$.  For $k=1$ you lose with probability $\frac 15$.  For $k=2$ you lose if the first item is not $0$ (probability $\frac 45$) and the second adds to zero (probability $\frac 14$).  So you lose again with probability $\frac 15$.  If the prime is $2$ you should do $k=2$

Comment: @RossMillikan You're right. I removed that.

Comment: @RossMillikan Is it obvious that it's truly a $\frac{1}p$ chance that the element is available and you pick it? It's not clear to me that the probability that the element is unavailable is always just $\frac{k-1}p$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt:  I think it is clear in the case of prime groups other than $C_2$.  It is the same idea that when drawing cards the chance the first is an ace is the same as the chance the last is an ace.  I think it applies to all groups but I can't get there.

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't quite see why it's the same, since what we're looking for changing based on what we've seen - but I thought of another argument since posting. In particular $G$ acts on its subsets by setting $gS=\{gs:s\in S\}$ - if $G$ has prime order, then every orbit of this action with proper non-empty subsets has exactly one subset that sums to zero - generally, this works whenever $k$ doesn't divide $|G|$. With $C_4$, one only gets a $\frac{1}6$ chance of getting $0$ if you pick two elements, since the only way to do it is $1+3=0$ - so $k$ does matter, and should be $1$ or $3$.

Comment: If I didn't make a mistake, for an elementary abelian $2$-group of order at least $4$, the probability is $1/|G|$ at $k=1$, $0$ at $k=2$ and then $1/|G|$ again at $k=3$.

Comment: Interesting problem! I would be surprised if you ever can do better than $1/|G|$, although I can't prove it at the moment. (By the above comment, there are non-trivial values where the probability is $1/|G|$.)

Comment: @verret I just found an example where you get better than $1/|G|$ - for $C_6$ with $k=3$ or $k=4$, you get a $1/5$ chance of success. (Gathering data, I can safely say I have no idea what's going on)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a program in magma that computes this. The output is below. First are the abelian invariants, the the probability, as $k$ runs from $1$ to $|G|$. The code is at the end  (you can run it here:http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)
It would be easy to run it further, or modify to compute the maximum $k$, etc.

---

[ 2 ]

[ 1/2, 0 ]

[ 3 ]

[ 1/3, 1/3, 1 ]

[ 4 ]

[ 1/4, 1/6, 1/4, 0 ]

[ 2, 2 ]

[ 1/4, 0, 1/4, 1 ]

[ 5 ]

[ 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1 ]

[ 6 ]

[ 1/6, 2/15, 1/5, 1/5, 1/6, 0 ]

[ 7 ]

[ 1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1 ]

[ 8 ]

[ 1/8, 3/28, 1/8, 9/70, 1/8, 3/28, 1/8, 0 ]

[ 2, 4 ]

[ 1/8, 1/14, 1/8, 1/7, 1/8, 1/14, 1/8, 1 ]

[ 2, 2, 2 ]

[ 1/8, 0, 1/8, 1/5, 1/8, 0, 1/8, 1 ]

[ 9 ]

[ 1/9, 1/9, 5/42, 1/9, 1/9, 5/42, 1/9, 1/9, 1 ]

[ 3, 3 ]

[ 1/9, 1/9, 1/7, 1/9, 1/9, 1/7, 1/9, 1/9, 1 ]

[ 10 ]

[ 1/10, 4/45, 1/10, 11/105, 13/126, 2/21, 1/10, 1/9, 1/10, 0 ]

[ 11 ]

[ 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1 ]

[ 12 ]

[ 1/12, 5/66, 19/220, 14/165, 1/12, 19/231, 1/12, 43/495, 19/220, 5/66, 1/12, 0
]

[ 2, 6 ]

[ 1/12, 2/33, 19/220, 1/11, 1/12, 6/77, 1/12, 1/11, 19/220, 2/33, 1/12, 1 ]

[ 13 ]

[ 1/13, 1/13, 1/13, 1/13, 1/13, 1/13, 1/13, 1/13, 1/13, 1/13, 1/13, 1/13, 1 ]

[ 14 ]

[ 1/14, 6/91, 1/14, 73/1001, 1/14, 212/3003, 41/572, 31/429, 1/14, 10/143, 1/14,
1/13, 1/14, 0 ]

[ 15 ]

[ 1/15, 1/15, 31/455, 1/15, 67/1001, 67/1001, 1/15, 1/15, 67/1001, 67/1001,
1/15, 31/455, 1/15, 1/15, 1 ]

---

You can run it here:
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

Here is the program:

---

for n in [2..15] do

for i in [1..NumberOfSmallGroups(n)] do

G:=SmallGroup(n,i);

if IsAbelian(G) then

AbelianInvariants(G);

list:=[];

for k in [1..n] do

f:=NumberingMap(G);

N:={1..n};

good:={};

Subs:=Subsets(N,k);

for S in Subsets(N,k) do

prod:=Identity(G);

for s in S do

prod:=prod*(s@@f);

end for;

if prod eq Identity(G) then

good:=good join {S};

end if;

end for;

list[k]:=#good/#Subs;

end for;

list;

end if;

end for;

end for;